# Randomly sample dataframe (slice_sample) and calculate summary statistics after using group_by, and iterate 999 times?

Tags: r, dplyr, iteration, tidyr

I would like to resample my dataframe (data_long) and calculate summary statistics (mean and standard deviation) of a numeric response variable (experience), after grouping data based on two categorical factors (ID = respondentID, and year). I would then like this process to be iterated, say 999 times, and average the above statistics for plotting (to compare to the whole dataset). If possible, I would like to resample the data frame using various sample sizes, but happy to do that with separate code for each sample size.

Here is an example for a sample size of 50. A key thing to note here is that there are differing number of rows for ID (e.g., some ID's have experience values for all years, some ID's only some years) hence the need to ungroup() after nesting.

```
# I can calculate the summary statistics for one iteration,   
# and for one sample size at a time:

subsample_50 <- data_long %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
                nest() %>%  
                ungroup() %>%
                slice_sample(n = 50) %>% unnest() %>% 
                group_by(ID, year) %>% 
                summarise(mean = mean(experience),
                          sd = sd((experience)))

> subsample_50
# A tibble: 198 × 4
# Groups:   ID [50]
   ID                year        mean    sd
   <chr>             <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 R_01VoZcSSa9AHcEJ 1995-10-06  5    0    
 2 R_01VoZcSSa9AHcEJ 2000-10-06  4    0    
 3 R_01VoZcSSa9AHcEJ 2005-10-06  4    0    
 4 R_01VoZcSSa9AHcEJ 2010-10-06  2    0    
 5 R_01VoZcSSa9AHcEJ 2015-10-06  2    0    
 6 R_0chSVxbdf6fcjgp 1995-10-06  5    0    
 7 R_0chSVxbdf6fcjgp 2000-10-06  5    0    
 8 R_0chSVxbdf6fcjgp 2005-10-06  4.17 0.408
 9 R_0chSVxbdf6fcjgp 2010-10-06  2.83 0.408
10 R_0chSVxbdf6fcjgp 2015-10-06  1.5  0.548
# ℹ 188 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

```
# I can also manually perform the calculations manually for   
# each sample size, and put the data together:

# Do this manually for two different samples sizes

subsample_50_a <- data_long %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
                nest() %>%  
                ungroup() %>%
                slice_sample(n = 50) %>% unnest() %>% 
                group_by(year) %>% 
                summarise(mean = mean(experience),
                          sd = sd((experience)))

subsample_50_b <- data_long %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
                nest() %>%  
                ungroup() %>%
                slice_sample(n = 50) %>% unnest() %>% 
                group_by(year) %>% 
                summarise(mean = mean(experience),
                          sd = sd((experience)))

mean_calc <- bind_rows(subsample_50_a, subsample_50_b) 
mean_calc <- mean_calc %>%
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(experience = mean(mean),
            sd = sd((mean)))

> mean_calc
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  year       experience    sd
  <date>          <dbl> <dbl>
1 1975-10-06       4.49 0.413
2 1985-10-06       4.66 0.372
3 1995-10-06       4.18 0.602
4 2000-10-06       3.89 0.926
5 2005-10-06       3.48 0.971
6 2010-10-06       2.57 0.940
7 2015-10-06       2.42 1.10
```

I would really like to automate performing these calculate around 999 times. Added bonus if we can do it across multiple sample sizes (e.g. n = 10, n = 50, n = 100), and then iterate this entire process 999 times.

The structure of the mean_calc df is ultimately the output that I am looking for (potentially with a new column for sample_size, just instead of calculating the mean and sd once, the summary statistics are calculated 999 times and averaged.

I have tried to do this myself using the below code, but I am having issues.

```
means <- data_long %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  crossing(sample_size=c(10,50,100), iter = seq(1:999)) %>% 
  mutate(sample_data = map2(data, sample_size, ~sample_n(.x,.y))) %>% 
  mutate(calc = map(sample_data, 
                    ~summarise(.,mean = mean(experience),sd = sd((experience))))) %>% 
  select(year, sample_size, iter, calc) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  group_by(year, sample_size) %>%
  arrange(sample_size, ID, year)


Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `sample_data = map2(data, sample_size, ~sample_n(.x, .y))`.
Caused by error in `map2()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `sample_n()`:
! Can't compute indices.
Caused by error:
! `size` must be less than or equal to 4 (size of data).
ℹ set `replace = TRUE` to use sampling with replacement.
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: If you can do your resampling once, then wrap it with `replicate(999, simplify=FALSE, <yourcodehere>)`. The `<yourcodehere>` can be a full expression (many lines) or you might prefer to make a simple function that does the sampling/aggregation and you just call a single function.